# Rotate $n$ points on circle with Lebesgue Measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Here is the statement I want to prove.

> Suppose that $\mathbb{S}^1$ with the circular Lebesgue measure of $A$ satisfies $\mu(A)>1-n^{-1}$ and that $B$ contains at most $n$ points. Show that some rotation carries $B$ into $A$.

I believe this question should be done by induction. The case for 1 and 2 points are easy. For two points, suppose that $x_2$ cannot be in $A$ for any rotation. We can let $x_1$ traverse through $A$, then we create a disjoint measurable sets with the same measure as $A$, which contradicts $\mu(\mathbb{S}^1)=1$.

However, I find it pretty hard to generalize this idea to $n$ points. Since it really depends on which $n-1$ points should be assumed in $A$. Does anyone have any idea for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for $n=2$ is already a good idea, but if you think about these things a little bit different, then it will be easier to generalize to higher $n$.

**Hint**:

The set of rotations on $\mathbb S^1$ is basically $\mathbb S^1$ itself.
We can also have the circular Lebesgue measure on the set of rotations.

What is the measure (probability) of the set of rotations such that $x_1\in A$
holds?
What is the measure of the set of rotations such that $x_1\not\in A$
holds?

If you solved these, then consider:
What can we say about the measure of the set of rotations such that
$x_i\not\in A$ for some $i$?

It should turn out that the measure for the opposite event (that all $x_i$ are in $A$) is nonzero, and thus the set of possible rotations is nonempty.

Comment: That's excellent! Thanks!